# Manually deep-copy objects that reference each other

Tags: java, deep-copy

Lets say I have two classes, Axon and Neuron, where Axon has an array of type Neuron, and Neuron has ArrayLists of type Axon:

```
public class Axon {
    public Axon(Neuron n1, Neuron n2) {
        pair = new Neuron[2];
        pair[0] = n1;
        pair[1] = n2;
        strength = 0;
    }
    public Neuron[] pair;
    public double strength;

public class Neuron {
    public Neuron() {
        axons = new ArrayList<>();
        inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        used = new ArrayList<>();
        override = -1;
    }
    public ArrayList<Axon> axons;
    public ArrayList<Double> inputs;
    public ArrayList<Axon> used;
    public double override;
}
```

How could I make a deep-copy method for these objects in the constructors of each class so that the fields in a new Axon reference the new Neurons and the fields in a new Neuron reference the new Axons, without causing an infinite loop of instantiations? I am trying to avoid using other methods of deep-copying, such as Serialization, in order to avoid performance bottlenecks.

Comment: More to the point, why are your objects designed this way?

Comment: They are designed this way so that rather than one Neuron accessing another directly, it must do so indirectly through an Axon.

Comment: The way to do it is to use an `IdentityHashMap` to 1) detect that you have copied a node and 2) record what you copied it as.  See linked Q&A